# How to use capture->retrieve()? Initial value of reference to non const must be an lvalue

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, lvalue

I'm trying to refactor my project and get rid of cvQueryFrame and other "obsolete" functions.

I'm new in C++. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
cv::Mat* frame;
OpenCVEngine* cve;

private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

cve->capture->retrieve(&frame);

// (...) do something with frame
}
```

I have error on `cve->capture->retrieve(&frame);`:

> Initial value of reference to non const must be an lvalue

And:

> error C2664: 'bool cv::VideoCapture::retrieve(cv::Mat &,int)' : cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'cv::Mat &'

My OpenCVEngine class header:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

class OpenCVEngine
{
public:
    OpenCVEngine();
    ~OpenCVEngine();

    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ MatToBitmap(const cv::Mat& img);

    cv::VideoCapture* capture;

private:

};
```

My OpenCVEngine class code:

```
#include "OpenCvEngine.h"

using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;

OpenCVEngine::OpenCVEngine()
{

    capture = &cv::VideoCapture(0);

    //cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    //cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);


    if (!capture->isOpened())
    {
        // todo: error handling
    }
}

OpenCVEngine::~OpenCVEngine()
{
    capture->release();

}

System::Drawing::Bitmap^ MatToBitmap(const cv::Mat& img)
{
    // (...) not important
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, but try using a `Mat frame` instead of a `Mat* frame`. Or `retrieve(*frame);`

Comment: "I'm new in C++" - then - do yourself a favour, and **do not use cli**. also: `capture = &cv::VideoCapture(0);`  <--will destroy itself, when leaving OpenCVEngine::OpenCVEngine() . you cannot take the address of a local construct.

Comment: Can I avoid CLI and use .NET forms?